# Is there a way to set width of <input type='file'/> for showing in Firefox?

Tags: file, firefox, input, width

All the CSS attributes apply to the `<input type='file'/>` don't work on FF, but work on most other browsers.

Just can't even set the width. Any solution? No JS please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you set the size attribute?

```
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
```

Firefox doesn't support setting the size via CSS.

Comment: but attribute 'size' is measured in characters (font & font size dependent), and it's hard to measure

Comment: It's still the only way. Other than that, what you are trying to do isn't possible as FF doesn't support it.

Comment: This does not work, after selecting a very long file name, it still exceeds the boundaries of the input field.

Answer (score 13):

I wouldn't have a clue if anyone still finds this thread, but just in case...

```
input[type="file"] {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

...worked for me. Cuts the overlap off, but at least it doesn't over- or underlap anymore

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

What if

```
<input type="file" name="file_to_upload" id="file_to_upload" style="max-width:75px;">
```

For me works in FF 37.0.1. But possibly in older versions does not work